# Integrating Angular 2 with React

Tags: reactjs, angular

Has anybody seen any good integration using both Angular 2 and React? This video indicates that it's possible: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQM0K6YG18s

I would really like to have the below in my new project if that's possible:

- Angular 2 web worker, service worker - https://www.oreilly.com/ideas/angular-2-and-the-future-of-html5-apps - e.g. to separate UI drawing and calculation to run on different CPU cores
- Redux data flow - e.g. maybe using react-redux or ng2-redux to connect container component with presentational component
- React inline style - e.g. Radium - http://stack.formidable.com/radium/, and this video explains why: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NoaxsCi13yQ

The challenges:

- How do I draw a line between the code that should be written in Angular 2 and React
- What should be compiled first, React JSX or Typescript? - this video shows that Typescript with React is not easy: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9PTa9-PPVAc

I know this question is likely not to have a definite answer, but if anybody know any active project trying to solve this (I can't find it), it would massively help my investigation.

Thanks in advance.

---

**Update in Aug/2016**

It's worth pointing out that **react-typescript** is doable, and there is now an reliable (created by the mobx creator) boilerplate [mobx-react-typescript-boilerplate](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react-typescript-boilerplate) available (shame on me I haven't tried).

For anybody who has interest, [mobx](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx) is a functional reactive framework that works well with React and came after Redux. See [State Management is Easy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ApmSsu3qnf0) on Youtube.

Comment: I had come across some article which showcase the mix usage of angular 1 and react.

There they had implemented react components in the directives/custom-elements and state management was not possible, as data is being handled by angular.

In that context, if you write static (stateless) components, then it is fairly possible.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like what you are describing is https://github.com/ngReact/ngReact . Quite like to wait and see if there is an Angular 2 version to be developed. Angular 1 doesn't have all the desired nice things I put in the question. I personally would only use React without integrating with Angular 1

Comment: Detali information how to connect Angular and React you can find hire: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54408694/connect-angular-application-with-reactjs-app/54408718